# C# Azure function - how to use CrmOnline API Connection in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, dynamics-crm-online

I know we can use the API connection with Logic Apps straight forward,

But I want to use CRMOnline API Connection with Azure Function, tried google search so can see example of organizationproxy only which is simple.

I appreciate someone can send me some code snippet or link of example of how to call the API connection from the Azure functions and use the payloads.
[image: Azure portal]

Comment: Honestly I don't think API connection can be used by Azure function.

Comment: As Azure portal API connection description is saying we should be able to use it with Azure function, that why I asked this question?

Comment: Yes but I dont think it is possible

Comment: @Thomas - question is about "how can we use it as API Connections in function" as per description. 
We developer can assume, but i think API Connection should be flexible and function should be able to consume it, its a great idea.

Comment: yeah but you should open a user voice or ask microsoft, the reality is that you cant for the moment

Comment: you can use MSI to connect to CRM Online so that you dont have to "deal" with lots of credentials

Comment: Thanks Thomas - yes raised it on MS azure function forum, will post here once I got any reply from MS Azure function team.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could just connect to CRM using the API's described [here](https://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2017/06/25/introducing-the-microsoft-dynamics-365-web-services/).

[Connecting to Microsoft Dynamics 365 using the SDK](https://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2017/06/25/connecting-to-microsoft-dynamics-365-using-the-sdk/)

```
CrmServiceClient client = new CrmServiceClient("Url=https://abc.crm4.dynamics.com; Username=james@email.co.uk; Password=password; authtype=Office365");

OrganizationServiceProxy organizationServiceProxy = client.OrganizationServiceProxy;

OrganizationWebProxyClient organizationWebProxyClient = client.OrganizationWebProxyClient;

IOrganizationService service = organizationServiceProxy ?? organizationWebProxyClient as IOrganizationService;
```

[Create, retrieve, update, & delete 365 data in a late bound fashion](https://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2017/06/25/create-retrieve-update-delete-365-data-in-a-late-bound-fashion/)

```
Entity account = new Entity("account");

account["name"] = "James Account";

service.Create(account);
```

Comment: Thanks James, organizationProxy is currently i am using. But i am wondering if can use the API connection, than if i have lot of functions i can point all of them to use this API connection so that credentials and CRMonline link can be maintained at one place.